# Adding 2 hours to post time

Tags: php, time

How do I add 2 hours to this post time?

```
$config['post_date'] = '%d/%m/%y (%a) %H:%M:%S';
```

I've tried switching timezones but it doesn't change anything so I'm just going to add 2 hours manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant add `2 hours` using `strftime` format directly. Convert it to timestamp first, add the hours, then feed the format and the timestamp. Consider this example:

```
$date = strtotime('+2 hours', time());
$config['post_date'] = '%d/%m/%y (%a) %H:%M:%S'; // strftime format
$config['post_date'] = strftime($config['post_date'], $date);
echo strftime('%d/%m/%y (%a) %H:%M:%S') . '<br/>';
echo $config['post_date'];
```

Output:

```
21/06/14 (Sat) 19:59:59
21/06/14 (Sat) 21:59:59
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create a [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) object:

```
$date = new DateTime('2006-12-12 12:00:00');
```

And then you can use [`DateTime::modify`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php):

```
$date->modify('+2 hours');
```

Finally you can use [`DateTime::format`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) to format the date:

```
$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

**Edit:**

In your specific case the code would look like this:

```
$config = array('post_date' => '21/06/14 (Sat) 14:00:00');

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y (D) H:i:s', $config['post_date']);
$date->modify('+2 hours');
$config['post_date'] = $date->format('d/m/y (D) H:i:s');
```

Comment: How does that effect my 'post_date'? It didn't effect it.